# Agregar un html completo a un div

Tags: javascript, html

Que tal, estoy intentando agregar un fichero html a un div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> <!-- este div donde agregare un html-->
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

donde agregare otro html con otro dipo de contenido (con tablas por ejemplo)

cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: En lo posible no uses iframes, salvo que sea estrictamente necesario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenes que hacerlo con un `<iframe>`

ejemplo:

```
<iframe id="Example2"
    name="Example2"
    title="Example2"
    width="400"
    height="300"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=es-419&amp;geocode=&amp;q=buenos+aires&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=38.638819,80.859375&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Buenos+Aires,+Argentina&amp;z=11&amp;ll=-34.603723,-58.381593&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

[Mas datos en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Gracias @Eduardo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar Javascript:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello <b>world</b>!";
</script>
```

o JQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#demo").html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
});
```

Solo necesitas algo que dispare ese evento, por ejemplo un clic y lo podrás cambiar cada vez que el evento se ejecute.
Tu div deverá tener el ID "demo"

```
<div id="demo">
  ...
</div>
```

Tambien puedes hacerlo con php utilizando include:

```
<div id="demo">
  <?php
    include("ruta_del_html.htmlophp");
  ?>
</div>
```

Ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/AJAX) para leer el contenido del otro fichero HTML y escribirlo en tu página:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("ID_OBJETIVO").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "URL_DEL_HTML_QUE_QUIERES_LEER", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

O si usas una biblioteca como jQuery, puedes hacer algo aún más simple con funciones como [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) o [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "URL_DEL_HTML_QUE_QUIERES_LEER",
    success: function(datos) {
        $("#ID_OBJETIVO").html(datos);
    }
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro

Answer (score 1):

Si el contenido es una Pagina Web como GoogleMaps, como dice eduardo, debes usar un iframe ( que ya no se recomienda utilizar). De lo Contrario, si el código Html esta dentro de tu sitio, o es una partrialView lo podes hacer mediante Jquery.

```js
function insertHtml(){
$("#htmlins").html("<span>este codigo html fue insertado</span>")
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="htmlins">
 </div>
<input type="button" value="Insertar Html" onclick="insertHtml()"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder.